# Copy and convert all values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe, I have a column "UnixTime" and want to convert it to a new column containing the UTC time.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([1565691196, 1565691297, 1565691398], columns = ["UnixTime"])

unix_list = df["UnixTime"].tolist()
utc_list = []

for i in unix_list:
    i = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    utc_list.append(i)

df["UTC"] = utc_list
```

This works, but I guess there is a smarter approach?

Comment: what do  you mean by "smarter"?  faster? less line code?...

Comment: Less line code or possibly using functionalities of pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
df["UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df['UnixTime'], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by smarter approach is pandas-way and less code, then this is your answer :

```
df["UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df["UnixTime"], unit = "s")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, someone before has answered it, okay.